# Which journals and conferences would be most appropriate for new number-theoretic quantum algorithms?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, research

Non-super-slow review process and non-super-slow publication should take precedence.

Comment: I don't think this kind of questions should be on-topic here. It looks more like something that should be asked on academia.SE (though I'm not sure it's on-topic there either). [Discussion about journals/conferences is not listed among the accepted topics in the relevant help page](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (unless one considers this as a type of "resource recommendation", which I don't think is sensible).

Comment: Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! As @glS said above, this is on the broad side of questions we get here and is virtually asking for [career advice](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/319/23), so I'm afraid isn't really appropriate for this site

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for advice on where to publish, which is both broad and touching on career advice, which is off-topic